# How to change Glassmapper's BeginEditFrame enclosing html element

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

I am using Glassmapper's `BeginEditFrame` method to make a treelist editable in Experience Editor. I am using

```
<%using (BeginEditFrame(Model, "Edit Location", x => x.Locations)) {%>
<% if (HasLocations) {%>
'some code here'
<% else if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor){ %>
+Add Locations 
<%} %>
<%} %>
```

`+Add Location` text should be presented as in inline element and get displayed fine in the preview mode but in Experience Editor, the following gets appended:

```
<div class="scLooseFrameZone scEnabledChrome" sc_item="sitecore://master/{553F90DF-AC07-4941-B605-6F5F40270C57}?lang=en&amp;ver=1" sc-part-of="editframe">
    <span class="scChromeData">{"commands":[{"click":"javascript:Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.postRequest('webedit:fieldeditor(command={86DECE56-8BD2-4FCC-9992-627D812089F5},fields=Locations,id={553F90DF-AC07-4941-B605-6F5F40270C57})',null,false)","header":"Edit Fields","icon":"/temp/iconcache/people/16x16/cubes_blue.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/cubes_blue_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the following fields: Locations","type":null}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{553F90DF-AC07-4941-B605-6F5F40270C57}?lang=en&amp;ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Edit Location","expandedDisplayName":""}</span>
    +Add Locations
</div>
```

This div makes the `+Add Location` text as a block element and it shows up in the next line.

Is there a way I can change the Edit Frames enclosing tag from block element to inline element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can change the markup that's generated for Sitecore edit frames, but you could always style that specific edit frame differently.

For example, wrap your existing edit frame code in a new `div`:

```
<div class="edit-frame-inline">
    [your existing edit frame code here]
</div>
```

And then style that markup very specifically:

```
.edit-frame-inline div.scLooseFrameZone {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will be try this option if nothing else could be done to change the markup of editframes.

Comment: Did you end up trying this and did it work?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it worked. Although we have not chosen this as a solution because we will have to change most of the editframes of the solution. 
We have somehow managed to convince the editors to use Experience Editor for editing and preview for checking the final result.